# Colours plot vector based

Tags: r

I have a vector `z` like this

```
z <- as.numeric(as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")))
```

and for different days a data frame `df` like this

```
df[[1]]

    ID     LON     LAT

    A     1        1
    B     10        14
    C     12        13

df[[2]]

    ID     LON     LAT

    A     2         3
    B     11        18
    D     12        13

df[[3]]

    ID     LON     LAT

    A     13        1
    E     10        14
    D     12        13
```

where the `ID`s are the ones in `z` but can be different for every day.

I have assigned a colour to each element of the vector

```
range01 <- function(x)(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))
rainbow(7)
cRamp <- function(x){
  cols <- colorRamp(rainbow(7))(range01(x))
  apply(cols, 1, function(xt)rgb(xt[1], xt[2], xt[3], maxColorValue=255))
}
```

and what I would like to do is to plot for every day my `df` with the colours `cRamp(z)` but I am no able to link the `ID` value in every `df` with the one in `z`

Here is my code

```
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){

  plot(df[[i]]$LON,df[[i]]$LAT, col = cRamp(z))
  map(add=T,col="saddlebrown",interior = FALSE)
  legend("topleft", legend=c(unique(df[[i]]$ID)), col=cRamp(z))
}
```

but the colour for e.g. `ID` `A` are not the same for every day!

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, especially `dput(z)`. `range01(z)` results in `Error in x - min(x) : non-numeric argument to binary operator` with a character vector.

Comment: Why `as.numeric(as.factor(…))`? That’s a very odd way of writing `seq_along(…)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
z <- LETTERS[1:7]

df <- list(
  data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:3],
             LON=c(1,10,12),
             LAT=c(1,14,13)),
  data.frame(ID=LETTERS[3:5],
             LON=c(2,11,18),
             LAT=c(2,9,20))
  )


layout(t(1:2))
for (i in 1:2){  
  plot(df[[i]]$LON, df[[i]]$LAT, 
       col = rainbow(length(z))[match(df[[i]]$ID,z)], 
       pch=16)
  legend("topleft", 
         legend=z, 
         col=rainbow(length(z)),
         pch=16)
}
```

[image]